# What is the name for the tall concrete tower in the southwest of Paris?

Tags: paris

I don't have a picture of it, but there is a very tall round cylindrical building that looks like a giant vent because it doesn't have any windows except for some openings at the top. But it's not in the list of the tallest buildings and it's nowhere to be found. it's very tall and visible in the background of the Eiffel tower when looking from the center area. Can someone please let me know what this is? Thanks. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_and_structures_in_the_Paris_region

Comment: Do you mean the white cylindrical thing here: https://imgur.com/SXulv2o ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the thing shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY55Z.jpg) from Google Maps, then it's the [Cheminée du Front de Seine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemin%C3%A9e_du_Front_de_Seine). It's a chimney from a steam heating plant.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer, this site is operated by the [Compagnie Parisienne de Chauffage Urbain](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compagnie_parisienne_de_chauffage_urbain), the chimney height is 130 m, it was built in 1970-71 ([more info](http://www.pss-archi.eu/immeubles/FR-75056-3531.html)).